# Azure IoT - Parse Avro Data for SQL Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm implementing an IoT proof of concept.  Sensor data is sent to an **Azure IoT Hub** and stored into **Blob Storage**.  I've created a streaming analytics job to pull the data from **Blob Storage** to **SQL Server**.  The job fails with the following error:

> Could not deserialize the input event(s) from resource '*my blob URL*' as Json. Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format

This error makes sense to me because the blob data looks like this:

> Objavro.codecnullavro.schemaÐ{"type":"record","name":"Message","namespace":"Microsoft.Azure.Devices","fields":[{"name":"EnqueuedTimeUtc","type":"string"},{"name":"Properties","type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}},{"name":"SystemProperties","type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}},{"name":"Body","type":["null","bytes"]}]} ¥ ¤ÒE+(i#œžMú82018-03-18T13:31:34.3590000Z $connectionDeviceIdPOCGateway(connectionAuthMethod–{"scope":"hub","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}8connectionDeviceGenerationId$636561592643859647contentTypetext/plaincontentEncoding enqueuedTime82018-03-18T13:31:34.3590000Z °{"ack":false,"adr":false,"appeui":"6c-4e-ef-66-f4-79-86-a6","chan":0,"cls":0,"codr":"4/5","datr":"SF7BW125","deveui":"00-80-00-00-00-00-be-b9","freq":"902.3","lsnr":8.5,"mhdr":"4001000000001500","modu":"LORA","opts":"testblobtosql","port":1,"rfch":0,"rssi":-53,"seqn":21,"size":20,"timestamp":"2018-03-18T00:09:31.185936Z","tmst":703423011,"payload":"\u000e\u0001\u0007\u000e\b\u00064>\u0005\u0001;\u000b\u0001z","eui":"00-80-00-00-00-00-be-b9","_msgid":"e43d4999.1bc2b8"}¥ ¤ÒE+(i#œžM

IoT Hub uses [Avro compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) on the incoming data which adds some 'junk' to the JSON that the SQL (as stream output) can't handle.

I'd like to leverage as many modules in Azure as I can as this POC may turn into a device management solution with provisioning, authentication, reporting, etc.

Is there a way to parse the Avro noise out of the JSON in Azure?  Perhaps a custom **Function** in the **Streaming** process that can do this?

It seems odd that Azure would not already offer this.

Comment: why are you first storing the data to blob and then reading the data from the Avro file instead of using an Azure Stream Analytics job to listen directly to the IoT Hub messages endpoint and write to SQL?

Comment: I think I may have tried that but will revisit and see if I can get further along.  Thank you!

Comment: I mean it's mostly a good idea to also store your raw data on blob for later replay or analytics, but the pipeline: "IoT Hub -> Azure Stream Analytics -> SQL DB" should certainly work

Comment: @silent - Finally got around to testing this witih iothub -> stream analytics -> blob and the data still has avro junk in it :(